# How to redirect to my profile page in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Have two form on same page one is registration and another is login and this is my login process code

```
public function login() {

    //print_r($_POST);die;
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pw', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        if (isset($_POST) && ($_POST['login'] == 'Login')) {
            $data['login_errors'] = validation_errors();
            $this->load->view('Public/register', $data);
        }
    } else {
        $this->load->database();
        $where = '';
        $where = array('email' => $_POST['user_name'], 'password' => $_POST['pw']);
        $rec = $this->db->select('*')->from('user')
                        ->where($where)
                        ->get()->result_array();
      if(!empty($rec)){

        $this->session->set_userdata('user',$rec);
        $this->load->view('Public/profile');


      }else{
         $data = array(
                'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
                );
                $this->load->view('Public/register', $data);
      }

    }
}
```

after login url is 
  http://localhost/ci/blog/login and view 
  loaded on it.It's looks like
  [profile template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymznu.png)

I am very much new in codeigniter.why the url 
  not change?It should be
  http://localhost/ci/blog/profile
  but when I am trying to redirect 
  redirect(base_url() . 'Public/profile'); it 
  gives 404 error. how to redirect it to
  profile page and change my url /profile.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a view will not change the URI in CodeIgniter. The URI is governed by the controller/method and the view is called by the controller.

This way, you can have a controller invoke multiple views at the same time (in my latest project, I invoke views for header, result and footer, for instance)

Getting familiar with the model-view-controller paradigm would be beneficial, but not required in this case. Just remember, as a rule of thumb, you URIs will be:
http://domain.tld/controller/method/

In layman terms, this way the URI will make it easier for you to know "what part is doing the work" regardless of what part handles drawing the result onscreen

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect('public/login');
redirect('public/regstration');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$this->load->view('Public/profile');
```

use

```
redirect('Public/profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you should Learn CodeIgniter [URL Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

> First load the helper `$this->load->helper('url');`

Then

```
redirect('Your_Controller_name/function_name');
In Your Case - redirect('Public/profile');
```

If your **controller** name is **Public** and **function** Name is **profile**